# Programming languages with equivalent of the Java 7 try-multiple-catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, java-7

Java 7 features a new way to catch multiple exceptions in one `catch` block, as shown below.

```
try
{
    //stuff that causes one or more of the exceptions below.
}
catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException | IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    //one of the above exceptions was thrown and caught
    //this code block will run if any of the above exceptions was caught
}
```

What other programming languages, if any, feature a similar way to capture multiple exceptions in one block, or remove the need to use a `catch` block for each exception? How do these languages implement this capture of multiple exceptions?

Comment: Scala catches them in `switch` statements

Comment: I tried this with abstract base classes in Python, but http://bugs.python.org/issue12029 outlawed my nasty hack.

Comment: this is more of a forced innovation to somewhat alleviate the excessive use of checked exceptions by java APIs. checked exception is great, until everybody think it's great and use it.

Answer (score 1):

The Ada programming language allows for the capture of multiple exception blocks, but I have no idea how this is implemented - but should be really interesting to know since Ada is VERY strongly typed. You can check the syntax here: [Annotated Ada Reference Manual](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-11-2.html)

Answer (score -1):

Javascript **requires** you to catch all exceptions in one `catch` block, since it's not statically typed.